# The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I use Qt creator 5.10.0 in Windows 7. I have built an exe using VC2010 c++ complier.

When I click the exe, it says QMTRACE.dll is lacking. When I add the dll into my project, error occurs: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2015-12-23T11:43:59
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui
QT       += serialport


greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MDT
TEMPLATE = app




SOURCES += main.cpp\
    mainwindow.cpp \
checkboxheader.cpp \
ft_file_info.cpp \
ui_dll_function.cpp \
ui_utility.cpp \
startprocess.cpp \
qmdttimer.cpp \
usbswitch.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
checkboxheader.h \
ft_file_info.h \
ui_dll_function.h \
ui_utility.h \
startprocess.h \
qmdttimer.h \
QMtrace.h \
usbswitch.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui

INCLUDEPATH += $PWD/DownloadLib



 INCLUDEPATH += C:/local/boost_1_71_0



 LIBS += -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" -lDownloadLib \
    -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" -lEfuseLibrary \
    -L"D:/EPS_projects/2018to2019/29_IOT_MDI/MDT/lib" -lQMTRACE \
```

My project is 32 bit， I used VC2010 32-BIT complier， QMTRACE.dll is x86

Comment: `C000007B` ... [STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsvc/2017/09/20/diagnosing-status_invalid_image_format-c000007b-errors/). May be, you have chosen the DLL for wrong platform? (From the link: _For instance, an x64 process is told to load a DLL, and the DLL that is found was built for x86.  Since a 32-bit DLL doesn't match the expected 64-bit architecture, the system returns the error that it has an invalid format._)

Comment: What I should do to solve my problem？

Comment: My project is 32 bit， I used VC2010 32-BIT complier， my dll is x86

Comment: It's sometimes surprising where the executable picks up the DLLs. (I have some bad experience about this.) If in doubt, it might be worth to check with [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). If I remember right, you have to be careful: there are two flavors of it - one for x86 executables and one for x64.